# react - mapping int value to a color in a color pallet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to draw a simple map with some simple circle objects on it. Each object has a field with an int value (can range between -1000 to 1000 for example). I would like to give each object a color based on the value, for example, I would like the higher the value the color would be closer to red, and the lower the value it would be close to blue. But the specific color pallet doesn't really matter.

Is there any simple way to do something like that? Are there any libs that give this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

This is crafted from my earlier answer somewhere here in SO. What it does, it gets the hex value of certain colour group (R, G, B, A [for alpha channel]). Now the hex value is emphasised based on the actual passed value (I made a functional example, feel free to modify).

And you can overwrite any of the RGBA values directly if you want, like giving "0" or "255" to them directly.

```js
const getHex = (value) => Math.floor(value).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');

const getRGB = ({
  R = 0,
  G = 0,
  B = 0,
  A
}) => ['#', getHex(R), getHex(G), getHex(B), A].join('');

const testValues = [-1000, -750, -500, -250, 0, 250, 500, 750, 1000];


const results = testValues.map((value) => {
  // if negative, no red value at all, otherwise value multiplied between 0 - 255:
  const R = (Math.max(value, 0) > 0) ? value * 0.255 : 64;

  // green is quite obsolete in this case, but some emphasis for lightness:
  const G = (Math.abs(value) < 250) ?  Math.abs(value) * 0.128 : 32;

  // if negative, blue value is multiplied between 0 - 255, otherwise value 0:
  const B = (Math.min(value, 0) < 0) ? Math.abs(value) * 0.255 : 64;

  return getRGB({ R, G, B });
});



// TESTING PURPOSES:
const showResult = (result, i) => {
  const textItem = document.createElement('div');
  textItem.textContent = `#${i}`;
  textItem.style.color = result;

  document.body.appendChild(textItem);
};

results.forEach(showResult);
```